# Don't show slider html code on mobile devices?

Tags: html, css

I'm busy with a new website, the only thing is, I don't wanna show the slider on mobile pages... I searched trough the internet and the only thing I found was CSS' media queries. Still, that doesn't really help  since my slider will still display the images, which is really messed up... This is my slider code:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="slider/1.png" style="width:100%; height:700px;"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="slider/2.png" style="width:100%; height:700px;"/>
      </li>
      <li class="slide">
        <img src="slider/3.png" style="width:100%; height:700px;"/>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And of course some jQuery, which I guess won't be a problem.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried ?

Comment: I tried the stuff with Media queries. I don't have any idea what to do more... I don't know any solutions for anything like this trough Javascript, PHP, HTML etc...

Comment: You could check for mobile device first (I use [MobileESP](http://blog.mobileesp.com/), and then either echo the slider (php) if you're not on mobile, or remove the slider if you are (combination of php and js)

Comment: I'm asking for code since the media queries is the rigth approach, but since you tried it, there must be some kind of a problem with your code. (or you simply forgot to add the viewport tag)

Comment: Can you use a bit of PHP?

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
.slider {display:none}
}
```

use the max-width you want for this ,and the slider won't be displayed from that resolution and down

Comment: keep in mind that this also hides the slider in desktop browsers that are less wide than that

Comment: You make a temporary solution because it will load on mobile too but not display.
It will take the same load as exist slider in mobile.